# how to run a linux program faster after its first execution

Tags: linux, bash, memory, cache

I use a Sophos antivirus program to scan email in antispam software ASSP, server OS Centos 7.4, MTA EXIM.

It run in this way

```
/usr/local/bin/savscan -sc -s -archive /file
```

It works very well to block malware but there is a problem. Every time savscan executes
it needs to load in memory all its virus signatures , approximately 6 seconds only to start .

If you consider that in the server I receive about 40 email per minute , it's a huge waste of time and resources. I already contacted Sophos and they told me that they are not interested to create 
a scanner daemon such as clamAV daemon does...

So my question is , is there any way to run  /usr/local/bin/savscan faster after its first execution ? Could it possible to run it as daemon , or put in memory the program after first execution so that the next executions will be much faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is not cleared if not required, so the program itself is probably still
in memory.

It is the program itself that needs those 6 seconds for its initialization.
The file should already be in memory, as well, so the disk might not be the
most important factor.

I suggest to trace during these 6 seconds the program's
[use of CPU and disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process),
to see where is the this time spent.

If it is mostly the disk, you might be able to migrate the program and
its signatures file to a
[RAM disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/creating-a-ram-disk-on-linux).

If the problem is in using the CPU, there is no solution except switching antivirus.